# Answer appears answered in the list, but no answer was chosen in the post itself

Tags: bug, user-interface, accepted-answer

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13439560/575527) I just answered appears to have a chosen answer in the [JavaScript category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). Knowing that only I answered the question, I assumed that my answer was chosen. However, when I viewed the post, it's not. Even my reputation seems to have no change as well. I'm also above 10k so I should see deleted answers, if any, but there's none as well.

Comment: Any chance you got confused in the colors? Do you have screenshot?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I guess I did. But it the explanation about the cache also helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to caching. The OP accepted an answer, then changed his mind and un-accepted. In fact, in my browser, the question is *not* shown as having an accepted answer:

[image: question *without* accepted answer]

When an OP accepts, then unaccepts an answer, the 'accepted' status of the question can still be cached in listings. You'd have gained, then lost 15 points, which if that occurred within the same day, is not listed in your reputation.